# Why does React randomly chose a different Stylesheet instead the one I imported?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a React App with the following folder structure.

[image: folder structure]

All my "pages" have their own Folder with a *.jsx* file and a *.css* to style the page.

I imported the CSS in the HomePage.jsx like:

```
import '../HomePage/HomePageStyles.css';  //HomePage.jsx
```

So far, everything is working just fine. Then I created the *ChampionDetailPage.css* and imported it in the *ChampionDetailpage.jsx* like that.

```
import '../ChampionDetailPage/ChampionDetailPageStyles.css';  //ChampionDetailPage.jsx
```

Now things start to get funny. The *HomePages.jsx* suddenly start to use styles from *ChampionDetailpage.css* that have the same class names without any obvious reason.
The goes vice versa, so the ChampionDetailPage.jsx uses classes from the *HomePageStyles.css* as well.

For example, I have the class *.content-right* in both *.css* files

```
.content-right{  /* HomePage.css */
    width: 55%;
}

.content-right{  /* ChampionDetailStyles.css */
    display: flex;
    padding-right: 20px;
    flex-grow: 100;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

In this case, React somehow styles my *Homepage.jsx* with the *ChampionDetailPages.css* which is also visible in the Chrome dev tools.

[image: Chrome dev tools]

Why does that happen and how do I fix it?

Things I tried already:

- Changing the import eg. `import './ChampionDetailPageStyles.css';`
- Throwing the CSS into its own directory
  in both cases, the problem remains the same!

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What tool is handling those `import`s? It looks like it's just taking `import` in any file to mean "include this in the HTML" and so naturally, you get two sets of declarations that interfere with each other. Some tools will do prefixing and such so that the CSS only applies to the content rendered by the file you've imported it into, but not all do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have stylesheets with classes that overlap eachothers.

Then, the class that is taken in consideration is the one that was in the css that was loaded the last. This is why you have each of the two classes that are picked up randomly.

What you must know When you import a css this way:

- Its content is not scoped for your file that imports this css.
- It will be imported globally, and then, classes that are defined inside will be shared to every dom content of your aplication during its whole lifecycle.
- You have no control on the order of importation of your css over the time.

To summarize, the stylesheet is not actually picked up randomly, it is the one that happens to be loaded the last that overrides every class that was already defined in the previously loaded css.

Something to know, all the css that you import in your client application are **ALL** loaded at the bootstrap.

A better way to manage styles with React is to use [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/). A framework that permits to handle css with your program, and also to be able to scope your styles to your component, or to share it with several components.

Comment: So the best approach would be to just rename the classes to something unique? Or can I import the CSS in a way that it is scoped for my file?

Comment: yes, this is it. If you want style to be scoped to the component you work on, the best approach is to is to use https://emotion.sh/

Comment: i use frameworks which creates random unique classes for components like Ant Design or for small projects bem_convention is good